# SQL Server : index of multiple characters

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I recently found out that my links stored in the database do not open in new tabs (no `target="_blank"`). I made this script that adds it in.

My problem is that if the `Preamble` column has multiple links, only the first one will be updated with `target="_blank"`, how can I run this for all links in the column?

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(Preamble, CHARINDEX('>', Preamble, PATINDEX('%<a href%', Preamble)) - 1, 1, '" target="_blank"')
FROM 
    QuestionContainer
WHERE 
    Preamble LIKE '%<a href%'
```

The Preamble column contains other HTML markup and other text.

**Update**

So for some reason I was trying to add the `target="_blank"` to the end of the anchor tag, instead I can just add it to the start.
A simple `REPLACE(Preamble, '%<a href%', '<a target="_blank" href')` will hit all occurrences in a row and solve my problem. - Thanks Allan S. Hansen

Comment: Would something like `update questioncontainer set preamble = replace(preamble, '<a href', '<a href target="_blank" ')` not do it? (of course this doesn't take into account those where you've already done it, will need to replace those back first :)) Otherwise you'll need to write a loop / function to split your column and re-work your indexes

Comment: This. But only if none of them have it, otherwise you would have to exclude the ones containing "_blank".

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The Preamble column contains other HTML markup and other text.

Comment: That's why you need to replace the `<a href` with to ensure it doesn't trigger on other html

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen One of my links looks like this '<a href=https://some.website/default.asp">Department’s Purchasing and Procurement Instructions</a>'

Comment: `REPLACE('<a href=some.website/default.asp">Department’s Purchasing and Procurement Instructions</a>', '<a href', '<a target="_blank" href');` seems to work and then it's just replacing the actual text with your column and updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `REPLACE` function:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<a href="some1"><a href="some2">'
SELECT REPLACE(@s, '>', ' target="_blank">') AS Link
```

Output:

```
Link
<a href="some1" target="_blank"><a href="some2" target="_blank">
```

Apply to your statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Preamble, '>', ' target="_blank">')
FROM QuestionContainer
WHERE Preamble like '%<a href%'
```

EDIT, according to @Allan comment:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<a href="some1"></a><a href="some2"></a>'
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, '>', ' target="_blank">'), '</a target="_blank">', '</a>') AS Link
```

EDIT 2: if you have different type of tags then it makes sense to put replacement string in the beginnning:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<a href="some1"></a><a href="some2"></a><b>'
SELECT  REPLACE(@s, '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ') AS Link
```

Output:

```
Link
<a target="_blank" href="some1"></a><a target="_blank" href="some2"></a><b>
```

Comment: hyperlinks often end with a </a>

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri This makes sense, but I have ~100 rows, I will still have to copy paste the links into the DECLARE which is what I want to avoid.